# How to add an Object into a certain x,y position in a 2D array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am making a game in Java and need to add an Object into a certain part of a 2D 4x4 array of null objects. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```
import java.util.*;
class a_class{
    private int i;
    public a_class(int k){
        i=k;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.print(i+"\t");
    }
}
class Stack_help{
    public static void main(String []args){
        a_class [][]a=new a_class[4][4];//creating a new array of 2d objects
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                a[i][j] = new a_class(i);
                a[i][j].print();
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

`

Probably what you are asking just run this code you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
array[row][col] = object
```

Hope this helps!